# Telerik: WPF -> Green Theme not referenced by this project

Tags: c#, wpf, reference, telerik

I am getting an error:

> Assembly 'Telerik.Windows.Themes.Green' is not referenced by this
>   project.

From the picture below you can see that it definitely is in my list of References.  I apologize if this is a stupid question as I am fairly new to WPF (WinForms was my thing).  Anyone able to shed some light on this?

[image]

Comment: You must add implicit theme

Comment: Amine I was following this guide:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36806626/telerik-wpf-green-theme-not-referenced-by-this-project

I found that if I added the xaml files to the Themes Directory and then removed the "/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Green;component/" it loads but does not seem to apply the theme.